# How should I read the sentence of multiple objects

Tags: sentence-meaning, objects

This is a extract from session 6 'word power made easy Norman lewis' book.

"The orthodontist specializes in improving your "bite," retracting "buck," and by means of braces and other techniques seeing to it that every molar, incisor, bicuspid, etc. is exactly where it belongs in your mouth."

In above sentence I can't understand its syntactic.

How should I read the part of sentence after "and " with respect to subject "The Orthodontist."

Will It be

The orthodontist specializes in by means of braces and other techniques seeing.......

Or

The orthodontist specializes by means of braces and other techniques seeing........

Or

The orthodontist by means of braces and other techniques seeing.......

Help to understand the syntactic of the  sentence!

Answer (score 0):

The prepostional phrase "by means of braces and other techniques" is parathetical (and could have been set of with commas or brackets.

So the syntax is just a list of verb phrases, in gerund-participle form

The orthodontist specializes in:

- improving your "bite,"
- retracting "buck," and
  (by means of braces and other techniques)
- seeing to it that every molar, incisor, bicuspid, etc. is exactly where it belongs in your mouth.

The final item in this list contains several components. There is the subordinate clause marked by "that", and that clause contains a list of tooth names and a further subordinate clause marked by "where".

The expression "see to it that..." is idiomatic: "I saw to it that John was happy"

Comment: James K,  "by means of braces and other techniques " working as adverb here before "seeing"?

Comment: It's a prepostional phrase, which describes how the dentist will "see to it". I wouldn't say that it is "working as an adverb" any more than I'd say that an adverb is "working as a prepositional phrase".